# Running a single rails performance test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance-testing

I am trying to run a single benchmark in the `test/performance/` directory. kinda like `rake test:benchmark` would do, but only with a single test.

The reason for this is because the whole performance suite takes a fair amount of time to run, and I am only interested in doing tests the model that the change will effect at first.

I have tried this, but it does not setup the benchmarking environment:

```
ruby -Ilib:test test/performance/email_list_test.rb
```

Also tried rails benchmarker `EmailList.all`, but I believe that must be pulling from the standard unit tests.

Comment: I would trust this functionality to guard. I use rspec, but I'm assuming [guard-test](https://github.com/guard/guard-test) runs on save in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
rake test:benchmark TEST=test/performance/email_list_test.rb
```